# How is Levy distribution created?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I want to know why and how Levy distribution equation was obtained. What characteristics does it have that makes it necessary or useful?

Comment: A distribution is neither provable nor unprovable, it just is. You seem to have a specific context in mind, the one in which YOU encountered these distributions. If so, state it.

Comment: @did Oops. I wasn't asking whether distribution is provable - it's not a theorem. My question is, for what purpose is this distribution made?

Comment: (Quote) You seem to have a specific context in mind... state it. (Unquote)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading these:

http://academic2.american.edu/~jpnolan/stable/chap1.pdf , and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution , and

www.columbia.edu/~sk75/levy.pdf

Enjoy!

-A

Comment: Needs a long-overdue upvote!